# How does a HTML form provide access to children via it's object property? ( myForm.myInput.value )

Tags: javascript

This is probably a technical question just want to understand how it works.
So here is a simple form:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("test");
console.log(form.blah.value);
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input name="blah" value="ok">
</form>
```

As you can see it outputs "ok" taking from `form.blah.value`
However when you look at `form` object structure in devtools, there is no such property as `blah`

So my question is **how does the form element provide access to it's children via their id/name as a property while not showing it in it's own structure in devtools?**

We can do something similar to an object via [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), is this how form does it? Can we do the same thing to other html elements?